# renderedCallback method in child component not recognized (undefined) when variable passed from parent component

Tags: lightning-web-components, console, rendered, parent-to-child

I am trying to pass a variable from parent component to child component in LWC. But when I tried to access this variable in `renderedCallback` method of child component, it is showing `loanId` as `undefined`.

This is how I am passing variable loan-id in parent component

```
    <div class="form-view-col slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
      <c-core-tag-pills loan-id={loanId}> </c-core-tag-pills>
    </div>
```

My child component (coreTagPills.js) looks like this:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
export default class CoreTagPills extends LightningElement {
  @api loanId;
  renderedCallback() {
        console.log("LoanId " + this.loanId);
  }
}
```

Here in console, I am getting `this.loanId` as `undefined`. Kindly suggest an appropriate solution?

Comment: Where is the loanId coming from? It may be that the value hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: It's basically fetching the record from DB passed in the controller(.cls) and than using it in renderedCallback() of child class. I don't think it's the loading issue. Even tried to put it inside connectedCallback() but error still persists.

Comment: Without seeing the context surrounding this code, we can't give a definitive answer, but I can guarantee that if you're calling Apex code, the value will *definitely not* be available until after both connectedCallback and renderedCallback have fired at least once.

Comment: can you please add the javascript code which fetches the loanId in parent component? Also please make sure loanId attribute in Parent has some value before it gets passed down to child component.